# maven test class files are not getting loaded: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, maven

I am getting following error while running junit test file with maven:

> Caused
>   by:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:IllegalName:com/home/app/LoginDetailsTest

all my test class files are located at target\ **test-classes** and java class files are located at target\ **classes** directory.

since LoginDetailsTest located at target\ **test-classes**, it couldnot identify class files. how to solve this error?

spring xml file:

```
<bean id="loginDetails" class="com/home/app/LoginDetailsTest">
    <property name="loginDetailsService" ref="loginService" />
</bean>
```

I am running junit test file through eclipse by right click and run as junit test.

```
<error message="Cannot find class [/com/home/app/LoginDetailsTest] for bean with name &apos;loginDetails&apos; defined in class path resource [com/home/app/LoginDetails-ctx.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /com/home/app/LoginDetailsTest" type="org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException">org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [/com/home/app/LoginDetailsTest] for bean with name &apos;loginDetails&apos; defined in class path resource [com/home/app/LoginDetails-ctx.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /com/home/app/LoginDetailsTest
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.&lt;init&gt;(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.&lt;init&gt;(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.home.app.LoginDetailsTest.testLoginDetails(LoginDetailsTest.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /com/home/app/LoginDetailsTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.bea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the class name this way in Spring : "com.home.app.LoginDetailsTest", not this way "com/home/app/LoginDetailsTest"